# html & css, define different "types of tag"

Tags: html, css

I'm probably using the wrong vocabulary and that's is why i can't find the answer to my question.

I'm trying to find how to define multiple types of "tag" on css. for exemple i want to define two types of textarea.

```
<style type="text/css">
    textarea.1 {width: 100%; background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.7)}
    textarea.2 {width: 50%; background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.7)}
     A img.1 {width:40px ; height:40px;}
</style>
```

to be able to only call it like:

```
<textarea.1>
   ..
</textare.1>
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `id` or `class`. Note, they should not start with a number.

Comment: Just use `<textarea class="t1">`.

Comment: @Jefffrey `class` names cannot start with a number

Comment: You can not define new element names (tags) yourself. You can put class-attributes on existing elements, and make them look differently that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - don't use numbers as class indicators (don't use numbers as any variable, use letters). It does not work for CSS and generally causes problems.

What you want is to define a class for the textarea which you can refer to in the CSS. Like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    textarea.one {width: 100%; background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.7)}
    textarea.two {width: 50%; background-color:rgba(100,100,100,0.7)}
     A img.one {width:40px ; height:40px;}
</style>

<textarea class="one">
   ..
</textarea class="two">
```